# Extract the node with R

Tags: r, xpath

I would like to parse the table from link http://www.espn.com/nfl/team/schedule/_/name/bal/baltimore-ravens

All information I need is stored in node //tbody (XPath - //*[@id="my-teams-table"]/div[3]/div/table/tbody)

Now I'm trying in R with the XML package,

`html_page <- htmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
 topNode <- xmlRoot(html_page)
 content <- getNodeSet(topNode, "//tbody")`

However, this gives me an empty value.

Comment: Scraping ESPN is a violation of ToS/T&C and may cause civil & criminal penalties for those who help you.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rvest`

```
library(rvest)
tbl <- read_html(url)  %>%
            html_nodes("table") %>%
            html_table(fill = TRUE, header = TRUE) %>%
            as.data.frame
```

#### data

```
url <- "http://www.espn.com/nfl/team/schedule/_/name/bal/baltimore-ravens"
```